# EmguCV, Xamarin Forms, C#, ALPR (License Plate Recognition from Smartphone Camera)

Tags: c#, opencv, xamarin, emgucv, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Please, I need help with EmguCV ALPR, C#, Xamarin Forms.  There are some sample on the web for ALPR, but these require that you take a picture and load it in the the app.

What I am looking for is to use EmguCV in a Xamarin Forms App to recognize license plate from the smartphone camera and update the text on a label with the License plate as text.

Is this even posible?  Or it can only be done by images not live feeds from camera?

Please, please, please help.